# Change snappy compression to zstd compression in Mongo Atlas for collections

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I want to change Mongo Atlas snappy compression to zstd compression for a collection. How to achieve this in Atlas cloud.

Comment: It's not possible, user has no control over the replica set configuration

Answer (score 4):

The default compression used is snappy, but it is possible to change the compression for individual collections on creation using the following

```
db.createCollection("foo", {storageEngine: {wiredTiger: {configString: "block_compressor=zlib"}}})
```

The available options as of v4.4 are: snappy, zstd, zlib, and none

Comment: just note that the above example uses the zlib compression and not the zstd.

Comment: Is there any way to migrate an existing collection to a new compressor?

Comment: @Hackeron, the only way is to create a collection with the new compression algorithm, copy data to it from the current one and switch the collection in the end assuming all the incremental/delta changes are also synced